# How do I get rid of this item in my menu bar on macOS

Tags: menu-bar, macos

So I have this "Citrix Receiver" item in my menu bar and I want to remove it. I have looked to see if I have an app in my system by that name and there is nothing. I did a search and nothing comes up. I have used "App Cleaner" to search for it and try to clean it and nothing.

[image]
[image]

Can someone please tell me how I can get rid of it? It won't even open when I click on "Open Citrix Receiver". It is unresponsive. Is there a way I can remove it?

Comment: Maybe something in the KB Document will help you find where that's loading from. Have a look at: [How to Remove Files Remaining on System after Uninstalling Receiver for Mac](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX134237).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To uninstall the Citrix Receiver for Mac, open the
>   [CitrixReceiver.dmg](https://www.citrix.com/go/receiver.html) file and select Uninstall Citrix Receiver.
>
> After uninstalling the Receiver *and rebooting the system*, ensure
>   that the files or folders listed in this section have been removed
>   from your system. If they still exist, remove them manually.
>
> /Applications
>
> - Citrix Receiver.app
>
> /Library
>
> - /Internet plug-ins/CitrixICAClientPlugIn.plugin
> - /LaunchAgents/com.citrix.AuthManager_Mac.plist
> - /LaunchAgents/com.citrix.ServiceRecords.plist
>
> /Users/Shared
>
> - /Citrix/Receiver Integration (entire folder)
>
> ~/Library
>
> - /Internet plug-ins/CitrixICAClientPlugIn.plugin
> - /Application Support/Citrix Receiver
>
>   - CitrixID
>   - Config
>   - Module
> - /Preferences/com.citrix.receiver.nomas.plist
> - /Preferences/com.citrix.receiver.nomas.plist.lockfile
> - /Preferences/com.citrix.ReceiverFTU.AccountRecords.plist (added in 11.6)
> - /Preferences/com.citrix.ReceiverFTU.AccountRecords.plist.lockfile (added in 11.6)
>
> ~/Applications
>
> - Under this folder, you can delete any applications you previously added via the Receiver UI.
>
> /private/var/db/receipts
>
> - com.citrix.ICAClient.bom
> - com.citrix.ICAClient.plist

To get to some of these locations faster using Finder, hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (or use menu *Go > Go to Folder...*) and paste the location there.

More info on the [Citrix website](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX134237).